# AutoIt Script to run exe files

Tags: autoit, execution

I created an AutoIt script to install my executable. But when I run it, nothing is executed. My script:

```
Run("agent.exe", "C:\temp")
```

After saving and compiling (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>), nothing is executed. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Run("C:\temp\agent.exe")
```

Your code is telling it to run `agent.exe` in the current directory and telling `agent.exe` to use `C:\temp` as its working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use absolute paths. Otherwise you may end up in a situations like this one.

By using just a filename "agent.exe" your script assumes that the file is in the current working directory. This is fine as far as the working dir doesn't change.

Use this For example:

```
Run (@ScriptDir & "\agent.exe", @HomeDrive & "\temp")
```